# how to make alternate rows a tableview have a light grey background

Tags: uitableview

In order to enhance the visibility how can i have alternate rows in a tableview have a light grey backgound color. this tableview is displaying an sqlite table.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use modulus to check if indexPath.row is divisible by 2 to style the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
  cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
} else {
  cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that when doing something like this, you need to reload all visible rows below any insertion or deletion point (including row reordering).

Comment: @rmaddy is right, you would be best reloading the section, sandwiched between `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` if you want a nice animation.